# Sonar lint fix for generic class

Tags: java, sonarlint-intellij

I have the below code to instantiate all the service on the start of the application. Sonar lint on the IndicesFactory is complaining for generic raw type. What is the best way to fix this?

```
public class IndicesFactory {

private final Map<String, IndicesStrategy> indicesMap;

public IndicesFactory(List<IndicesStrategy> indicesStrategyList) {
    this.indicesMap = new HashMap<>();
    indicesStrategyList.forEach(strategy -> this.indicesMap.put(strategy.getOperation().toString(), strategy));
}

private IndicesStrategy getStrategy(String operation) {
    return this.indicesMap.get(operation);
}


public <T, R> R execute(String operation, T t) {
    return (R) getStrategy(operation).execute(t);
}}
```

And my IndicesStrategy interface has below code

```
public interface IndicesStrategy<operation extends Enum<?>, T, R extends 
  IndicesResponse> {

R execute(T t);

operation getOperation();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @TimMoore I know what a raw type is. The problem I m facing is how to apply that to a generic class like the one I have

Comment: You need to provide values for the type parameters wherever you use the generic type. I’m not sure what values are right for your use case, because the question doesn’t describe it, but I would guess you want wildcards `?`

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the raw type warnings, values need to be provided for the type parameters of `IndicesStrategy` wherever that type is used in `IndicesFactory`. It appears that this class needs to handle different types of `IndicesStrategy`, so it can use type wildcards (`?`) as the values:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class IndicesFactory {

    private final Map<String, IndicesStrategy<?, ?, ?>> indicesMap;

    public IndicesFactory(List<IndicesStrategy<?, ?, ?>> indicesStrategyList) {
        this.indicesMap = new HashMap<>();
        indicesStrategyList.forEach(strategy ->
                this.indicesMap.put(strategy.getOperation().toString(), strategy));
    }

    private IndicesStrategy<?, ?, ?> getStrategy(String operation) {
        return this.indicesMap.get(operation);
    }


    public <T, R extends IndicesResponse> R execute(String operation, T t) {
        IndicesStrategy<?, T, R> strategy =
                (IndicesStrategy<?, T, R>) getStrategy(operation);
        return strategy.execute(t);
    }
}
```

As an alternative equivalent, you might prefer to move the unchecked cast into the `getStrategy` method:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class IndicesFactory {

    private final Map<String, IndicesStrategy<?, ?, ?>> indicesMap;

    public IndicesFactory(List<IndicesStrategy<?, ?, ?>> indicesStrategyList) {
        this.indicesMap = new HashMap<>();
        indicesStrategyList.forEach(strategy ->
                this.indicesMap.put(strategy.getOperation().toString(), strategy));
    }

    private <T, R extends IndicesResponse> IndicesStrategy<?, T, R> getStrategy(String operation) {
        return (IndicesStrategy<?, T, R>) this.indicesMap.get(operation);
    }


    public <T, R extends IndicesResponse> R execute(String operation, T t) {
        IndicesStrategy<?, T, R> strategy = getStrategy(operation);
        return strategy.execute(t);
    }
}
```